# SQL Query help: Getting counts based on combination of columns efficently

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table (variable (unlimited variety), attr (exactly 3 different attributes), date, state (can only be 0, 1, or 2) ):

```
 ------------------------------------
| Variable | Attr |   Date   | State |
|------------------------------------|
|    V1    |  A1  |01/01/14  |  0    |      
|    V1    |  A1  |01/02/14  |  2    |           
|    V1    |  A1  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V1    |  A1  |01/04/14  |  2    |      
|    V1    |  A2  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V1    |  A2  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V1    |  A2  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V1    |  A2  |01/04/14  |  1    |  
|    V1    |  A3  |01/01/14  |  0    |      
|    V1    |  A3  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V1    |  A3  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V1    |  A3  |01/04/14  |  2    |  
|    V2    |  A1  |01/01/14  |  2    |      
|    V2    |  A1  |01/02/14  |  1    |           
|    V2    |  A1  |01/03/14  |  2    |     
|    V2    |  A1  |01/04/14  |  1    |      
|    V2    |  A2  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V2    |  A2  |01/02/14  |  2    |           
|    V2    |  A2  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V2    |  A2  |01/04/14  |  0    |  
|    V2    |  A3  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V2    |  A3  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V2    |  A3  |01/03/14  |  2    |     
|    V2    |  A3  |01/04/14  |  1    |  
|    V3    |  A1  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V3    |  A1  |01/02/14  |  2    |           
|    V3    |  A1  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V3    |  A1  |01/04/14  |  1    |      
|    V3    |  A2  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V3    |  A2  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V3    |  A2  |01/03/14  |  0    |     
|    V3    |  A2  |01/04/14  |  2    |  
|    V3    |  A3  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V3    |  A3  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V3    |  A3  |01/03/14  |  2    |     
|    V1    |  A3  |01/04/14  |  1    | 
|    .     |  .   |.         |  .    |
|    Vn    |  An  |n         |  n    | 
|----------|------|----------|-------|
```

The output I want (note count is completely random values for this example):

```
------------------------------------
| Variable | Attr | Count| State |
 ------------------------------------
|    V1    |  A1  | 50   |  0    |      
|    V1    |  A1  | 24   |  1    | 
|    V1    |  A1  | 22   |  2    |                
|    V1    |  A2  | 1    |  0    |       
|    V1    |  A2  | 0    |  1    |
|    V1    |  A2  | 15   |  2    |      
|    V1    |  A3  | 68   |  0    |
|    V1    |  A3  | 9    |  1    | 
|    V1    |  A3  | 34   |  2    |       
|    V2    |  A1  | 10   |  0    |               
|    V2    |  A1  | 0    |  1    |
|    V2    |  A1  | 25   |  2    |                   
|    V2    |  A2  | 48   |  0    |     
|    V2    |  A2  | 96   |  1    | 
|    V2    |  A2  | 14   |  2    |             
|    V2    |  A3  | 12   |  0    |     
|    V2    |  A3  | 3    |  1    |
|    V2    |  A3  | 0    |  2    |              
|    V3    |  A1  | 4    |  0    |     
|    V3    |  A1  | 5    |  1    |
|    V3    |  A1  | 8    |  2    |                     
|    V3    |  A2  | 19   |  0    |     
|    V3    |  A2  | 95   |  1    | 
|    V3    |  A2  | 26   |  2    |                   
|    V3    |  A3  | 4    |  0    |     
|    V3    |  A3  | 85   |  1    |
|    V3    |  A3  | 50   |  2    |   
|    .     |  .   |.     |  .    |
|    Vn    |  An  |n     |  n    | 
|----------|------|------|-------|
```

The first thing I want to do is to choose a variable + attr + state combination which I want to base my query off of. So lets say I choose V2 + A3 + 2. Next I want to go and find the dates of all rows where var = V2, attr = A3, and state = 2. Next I need to go through each of these dates and count all the other var + attr + state combinations. For example if V2 + A3 + 2 occurs on 01/01/14, 02/06/14, 02/07/14, 04/09/14, and 05/03/14 it would go through all the other variables on these dates and add up the occurrences for each var + attr + state combination. So the output would group each var + attr + state combination and the count for each of these combinations would show.

To complete this I am using the query:

```
SELECT  m2.variable, m2.attr, m2.state, COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable m1
JOIN    mytable m2
ON      m2.date = m1.date
WHERE   (m1.variable, m1.attr, m1.state) = ('V2', 'A3', 2)
GROUP BY
        m2.variable, m2.attr, m2.state
```

So this query essentially returns counts for the variable + attribute + state combination I chose. So this is just for one combination, but I would like to get counts for the possible combinations (~20,000 different variables x 5 different attributes x 3 different states).My initial approach was to write a script to substitute the combination variables (e.g. (m1.variable, m1.attr, m1.state) = (SUB_VAR1, SUB_VAR2, SUB_VAR3) )  and simply run through all combinations and return the counts (I am only interested in the highest 20 counts for each). I thought initially this might take a few hours to do. The problem is the query is VERY VERY SLOW, about 45 seconds to run for each combination. The table used here has about 15M - 20M rows (~20,000 variables x 5 attributes x 3 states  x 60 days) and the table is joining on itself so that is A LOT of rows to process, a months worth of processing. My primary key is Variable + Attr + Date and there is of course an index on this. I have tried creating a duplicate table but by using the MEMORY engine in hopes it would speed up the process, but it only increased the speed by about 5-10 seconds. I am not strong with query performance but I tried some other queries but they did not help. I am in need I think of a more efficient query or even a complete re-design of the tables possibly? I have tried various things which do not seem to work, any input on how to achieve the results I need in an effiecent way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the actual desired result, not random data, so if we try to test a solution we can tell if it's right?

Comment: There are no dates here

Comment: I don't have access to the database right now, but the results I provided are the exact same as the actual results, I just changed the name of the data under the variable column. As well, I cut off a lot because there are 50,000+ rows created. This result is for one combination.

Comment: Sorry Strawberry I do not know what you mean there is no dates?

Comment: What are you trying to do with all the different combinations, though? Do you want to add them together, or show them separately? That's why I want to see the full results you're looking for.

Comment: If you want to add them together, just remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I want to show them separately, or even if possible to show the results all at once.

Comment: If you did all combinations in one go, would you expect the result set to look like `basis_v, basis_a, basis_s, v, a, s, count`

Comment: Laurence yes exactly! A one go would be the most ideal, but I can manage if separate as well.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand you want to base the query off of all combinations. get the dates for those combinations and then count the number of other combinations that have that date .. if thats true then this will do what you want.

```
SELECT  Variable , Attr , COUNT(*) , State
FROM mytable 
WHERE date IN
(   SELECT date 
    FROM mytable  
    GROUP BY variable, attr, state
)
GROUP BY variable, attr, state
```

Comment: This is just a refactoring of his query. It doesn't address his question of doing it for every combination.

Comment: @Barmar I just realized he wants every combination and added that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Generate all the combinations using `cross join` and then use your query:

```
SELECT v.variable, a.attr, s.state, COUNT(m2.date)
FROM (select distinct variable from mytable) v cross join
     (select distinct attr from mytable) a cross join
     (select distinct state) from mytable) s left join
     mytable m
     on m.variable = v.variable and m.attr = a.attr and m.state = v.state left join
     mytable m2
     ON m2.date = m1.date and (m1.variable, m1.attr, m1.state) = ('V2', 'A3', 2)
GROUP BY v.variable, a.attr, s.state;
```

Comment: a few notes.. is it v.state or s.state? you have mytable m but then reference m1 is m and m1 supposed to be the same table?

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm this gives the answer you are expecting

```
select
    bases.variable as basis_v,
    bases.attr as basis_a,
    bases.state as basis_s,
    counts.variable,
    counts.attr,
    counts.state,
    count(*) as count
from 
    mytable bases
        inner join
    mytable counts
        on bases.date = counts.date
group by
    bases.variable,
    bases.attr,
    bases.state,
    counts.variable,
    counts.attr,
    counts.state
order by
    bases.variable,
    bases.attr,
    bases.state,
    counts.variable,
    counts.attr,
    counts.state;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63033/2)

Note also, I've not included all combinations of `v, a, s`, only those that actually occur.

This will still be fairly slow because of the self join, but at least you get all the results in one go. However, bear in mind there could be up to 20,000 x 20,000 of them!

Comment: Thinking about it, fairly slow is probably a vast understatement. This will do nested loops of 20,000,000 by 20,000,000.

Comment: I have deleted data (scaled down by about 1000% to make it much smaller). The results are exactly what I want! Now the performance just needs a big improvement. Would you mind sharing your plan?

Comment: Sorry, plan didn't work, I was going to create some part aggregated temporary tables based on dates, but then I realized they would still only be aggregating a single row. However, that's why the query went from three tables to two. To get any further I'd be looking at the "only interested in the top 20 of each basis" part. In SQL terms you'd want to be using `rank` or `row_number` for this, but MySQL doesn't directly support them.